# Update table by column index not by column name

Tags: mysql

I'm using MySql and I have `Products` table with columns `ID, name, price` (and others)

Usually you can update database like this:

```
Update Products 
Set price = 100
where ID = 5
```

But what I want to update a value with column index instead of column name. Like this:

```
Update Products 
Set "Third Column" = 100
where ID = 5
```

How to update table by column index?

Any ideas?

Comment: Why? What is the situation that will lead to this?

Comment: You can do this with dynamic SQL but not with a regular statement.

Comment: You can do this with `dynamic sql`, but I agree, why?

Answer (score 0):

As per the comments you can do it with dynamic SQL (not recommended) due to security implications or the below.

```
Update Products 
Set 
     ID = IF(colparameter=1, valueparam, ID),
     name = IF(colparameter=2, valueparam, name),
     price = IF(colparameter=3, valueparam, price)
where ID = 5
```

Even this I wouldn't recommend doing.

Comment: Your solution is also calling the column name.. it doesn't makes any difference.